# Renew previous IP address?

Tags: apache, xampp, ip

Due to a multi-day power outage, my IP address has changed. I have been running a server from home that hosts a website (Apache/MySQL via XAMPP) as well as several game servers (TF2). Prior to the power outage, there has been no issue with the IP changing for several months. After the power outage, my IP has changed and now the IP has to be updated with my domain name provider as well as all of the links to my servers (including players that have added the game servers to their favorites and with my database that tracks the servers). Is there a way to set the IP address (either on the server PC or on my Verizon router/modem) back to what it was prior to the outage so that I don't lose any previous visitors to my game servers?

Comment: Aks you ISP for static IP :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic Doesn't that cost a lot of $$$ ? Also, couldn't that have negative effects on the rest of my network? The server is running off of my home network.

Comment: "Is there a way to set the IP address (either on the server PC or on my Verizon router/modem) back to what it was prior to the outage so that I don't lose any previous visitors to my game servers?" No you get your IP from your ISP would be wierd if the customer could set there IP..

Comment: If you're not paying for a static IP then you're going to lose your IP once in a while. That's just how it works. Your ISP is spoiling you by giving you that for months on end. Some aggressively cycle over your IP several times a day.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at DynDNS?  Should take care of this problem. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Have a look here.

https://dyn.com/dynamic-dns/